# Process data on Firebase of Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I hope to upload data from Android app to Google Cloud Platform and do some basic machine learning/statistic operations. I have used firebase and upload the generated data on Android app to 'realtime database' on firebase of Google cloud platform. My next goal is to do some data processing, such as simple statistic and machine learning operations, I do not know how 'realtime database' could support these operations? If not, it seems Google Cloud Platform can do such operations in MySQL, how I transfer the data in 'realtime database' on firebase on My SQL? I am the fresh guy in GCP, hope get a clear direction. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [firebase_admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) library to access Realtime Database data. Then you can either store it using one of many [google cloud client libraries](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=library&type=&language=) or use it directly in ML Job.